# PHP name an un-named multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How can I change ['visits'][0] to a name: 'location_1', ['visits'][1] to: 'location_2', etc.?

```
(
    [visits] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 24682
                    [Address] => 1234 Some Street, Houston TX 77777
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 24685
                    [Address] => 2345 Any Street, Houston TX 77777
                )
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through and make a new array:

```
foreach ($array["visits"] as $key => $value) { 
     $newArray["location_".($key+1)] = $value;
}
```

Example at:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2bab7e7431f553faee32e028a0823b001214607

Comment: Perfect! And beautifully simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With a little tweaking, something like:

```
<?php

$things = 
[
    ['foo', 'bar'],
    ['big', 'fat', 'mama']
];

$desired = array_combine(
    array_map(
        function($v) {
            return 'location_' . $v;
        },
        range(1, count($things))
    ),
    $things
);

var_export($desired);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'location_1' => 
  array (
    0 => 'foo',
    1 => 'bar',
  ),
  'location_2' => 
  array (
    0 => 'big',
    1 => 'fat',
    2 => 'mama',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks!